# Regex Attempt | Matching Emojis and Pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

So I've been trying to match [this](https://pastebin.com/D58EkQHi) type of pattern for a while. I'm using [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) to test my things out, I ended up with this:

```
(\[★+\] [A-Za-z0-9]\s?-?[A-Za-z0-9] ?\w+?\s?[A-Za-z0-9]\s?\w+ ?\[?[A-Za-z0-9]\w+\]?[A-Za-z0-9]\s?\w+ ?\[?[A-Za-z0-9]-?\w+\])
```

This one hardly matched almost everything, as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puVcX.png). I'm still new to using RegEx but i figured out one the experts out here can help me.

The Regex need to match every entry, separated. In attempt to form a database.

Comment: Do you want to match the entries with a Christmas tree too or just the one with the stars?

Comment: Isn't a simple `(\[★+\].*)` enough? I got 117 separate matches, for every line where there is a star. It would be more helpful if you'd tell us what is the expected output or if you are trying to match multiple groups in every entry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one : `\[(★||)+\](\s[❤\w-]+\s?)+\[[\w-]+\]`

`\[(★||)+\]` matches [★] [] [] with as many star/tree/cake as possible

`(\s[❤\w-]+\s?)+` matches a space character followed by ❤ or A-Za-z0-9_ or - followed by a potential space (0 or 1), and all that as many time as possible

`\[[\w-]+\]` matches [ followed by as many as possible A-Za-z0-9_ or - followed by ]

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vNmF4O/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you a clean regexp since I don't know rules; by example:

- do you need to select only stars or emoticons "cake part", "tree" and anything else ?
- does a line always ends with ascii text between `[]` ?

I can give you a "large" regexp but there may be side effects, with more details we can make better regex

`^\[(.+)\] (.*?) \[([\w\-]+)\]$`

https://regex101.com/r/eU7vis/1

`^\[(.+)\]` Gets and ensures the first part (emoticon simple or multiple or any character between `[]`). We could limit authorized chars if you have constraints.

`(.*?)` Gets the minimum of characters (any character) as far as we are not matching next part

`\[[\w\-]+\]$` Gets and ensures string ends with text between `[]`. Authorized chars in this part are alphabet letters (lower and upper), digits, underscore  and hyphen.